# Can I do exposure bracketing as a burst of shots on a Nikon D5000?

Tags: nikon-d5000, bracketing, burst-mode, continuous-drive

Is it possible on Nikon D5000 to do AE bracketing in a burst?

Currently I've been able only to set bracketing mode but all three firings had to be done manually with the trigger button.

Comment: Just in case, I recommend to make sure that "Bracketing is correctly turned "On". You have to check in the settings, bottom right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you'll need to set the 'release mode' in your camera to 'Continuous' to get it to burst the three shots.
Also, reportedly, if your camera is on a self timer it will also take the three shots in a single button press after the time delay.

Comment: This, but you do have to hold the button down until all 3 shots are taken - it won't take 3 shots on one press on Continuous.

Comment: interesting! I'll try it tomorrow :)