# Is there a way to make the Nikon D5100 fire three auto-bracked shots with one press?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, bracketing

I have a Nikon D5100 and I can set it to auto bracket, where I fire 3 shots off and it brackets with ev +2, ev 0, and ev -2. That is okay, but is there a setting so that when I trigger the shutter release, it fires 3 shots automatically in rapid succession?

I ask because I have found that I can take my remote and fire off 3 shots as quickly as possible, but in windy conditions this still produces ghost when I merge them (so far the programs have been decent at removing ghost).

I know I cannot fire as quickly as the camera could fire, and did not know if there is a setting I am missing that would allow this. If there is not a setting, what are ways to speed up my shooting speed for capturing shots to merge into a HDR shot? (I am using a tripod and most of the time a remote.)

Comment: This is essentially the same question is [Can I do exposure bracketing as a burst of shots on a Nikon D5000?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/can-i-do-exposure-bracketing-as-a-burst-of-shots-on-a-nikon-d5000), except for the slight update in model number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your manual for the Sports or Burst mode - which should let you fire off (from what I can find for that model) at 4 fps (so 4 shots as fast as it can).

If using a remote - you should be able to hold down the button on the remote and hear the camera fire in rapid succession.

Edit: Ah - yes, only so much can be done about wind.

Comment: Holding the button on a wired remote works this way. Holding down the button on some wireless remotes does not.

Answer (score 4):

> I ask because I have found that I can take my remote and fire off 3
>   shots as quickly as possible, but in windy conditions this still
>   produces ghost when I merge them

Bursting shots in continuous mode may not be the answer; or at least, it may not solve your problem. In windy conditions the ghost you see is the difference in movement between the first and last shot. No matter how you look at it, it takes time to make each of those exposures, and movement can happen in that time. The 5100 can shoot at 4 frames-per-second, so at the *absolute fastest* it can go to get three shots a total of about 3/4 of a second will have elapsed. That's plenty of time for trees to move enough to introduce visible blur.

The only solution to eliminate movement and effectively get bracketed shots would be to have three cameras (one set to +2 EV, one 0 EV, and one -2 EV), and trigger them all at the same time.

Comment: One day when I can afford 3 cameras =>

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I realized that three cameras causes a different problem: no matter how close they are, they will still have a slightly different angle of view preventing perfect alignment. No good solutions!

Answer (score 4):

Go to menu and change timer settings.
I set my timer duration to 2seconds and increase shots to 3.
When fire shutter I get 3 bracketed shots but there is a pause between the shots.
It is better than having to shoot thrice but I hate the pause.

Canon T2i T3i just shoot 3 pictures even for single burst mode.

Answer (score 4):

I can do it on my Nikon D5000. On the Info screen bottom right select BKT and select AE2.0 then back in the Info screen from release mode select continuous. You can now hold down the shutter for three shots and it will give the 3 shots with 3 exposures for a HDR. It is possible to do some HDRs without a tripod doing this if there is enough light and you hold the camera steady enough.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could also look at making your tripod a little sturdier. Proving
   you have a fairly strong tripod to start with try hanging a weight
   from the middle of the tripod. The extra weight adds to the overall
   mass of the tripod and makes it harder to move in the wind. You can
   use your camera bag for this provided it has enough weight in it of
   course ;-)
2. Shoot one RAW and process it three times for the exposures you need.
   Provided you expose for the shadows - i.e. ensure you have enough
   detail in the shadows you can usually fix blown-out highlights (sky,
   lights, teeth etc) in post production.

For a comprehensive tutorial on HDR and RAW processing see http://www.littletimemachine.com/hdr_tutorial/.

Answer (score 2):

To take bracketed shorts on Nikon D5100, you have to press the trigger button 3 presses independently. However you can also hold down the trigger button and it will take 3 shots for you automatically.

when you bring the camera into auto bracket, the camera is smart enough to know that you are about to take bracketed shots. Therefore it automatically selects burst mode for you. Another nice feature is if you hold down the trigger button, it will automatically take 3 photos for you and stop. That is, it will not take 4 photos or more photos because you are in bracketed mode. This is a really nice feature of Nikon D5100.

If for any reason you could not take 3 shots at once due due to wind or something is moving in the front, make sure to use lock focus button (the one with the key). Hold that button down first and hold the trigger button, you will get 3 quick auto bracketed shots. You can later use them for HDR or what ever purpose you are intending it for.

Comment: +1 for this is exactly the same way how my Sony SLT works and how I'd presume all modern cameras work. Just keep the shutter release button down and three bracketed shots will follow.

Answer (score 2):

I bought a Nikon D5100 and I returned it for the same reason. When I set the camera to take 3 photos with different exposures, first of all, you have to put your camera on timer (10 seconds, a long time), and then in between shots the camera take 3 more seconds. During that time there is a lot of movement and there is no way to change that, unless how "enthusiast" said, you have to hold the trigger, which could also move the camera.

**Solution**: Buy the Canon T3i or T4i. In these cameras, you set the exposures, the quantity of photos, set the timer (only 2 seconds) and shoot.

**Result**: 3 shots very fast with different exposure.

Comment: You've returned the D5100, so it obviously doesn't matter, but: the self-timer delay can be set with custom function C3 to 20, 10, 5, or 2 seconds. The delay between shots (you cite 3 seconds) is going to be dependent upon a variety of things including shutter speed, high ISO noise reduction, Active D-Lighting settings, and many other things. In other words, the things you cite are not limitations, just misconfigurations for (what I'm guessing) your intent was.

Answer (score 1):

best solution, get a s/h Nikon D50 or D70. Both these cameras take three bracket shots ate different exposures with no delay so you can do it hand held. I used to have both of those cameras permanently set to HDR and the images were always stunning.
Thew following link shows photos I took with those cameras, though I have played around with the tones, so they may not be what you like.
https://plus.google.com/photos/116334091837292853642/albums/5774588388533852097?banner=pwa

Answer (score 1):

Further to my post. I have a 5100 and couldn't find a way to take the 3 frame auto bracketed photos, but I have just discovered that it is there and here is the video to show how to set the camera up for it.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXInETObaoI

Comment: Thanks for your input! We prefer the answers here be as self contained as possible. Rather than just posting a link that may or not always work, you should post at least a short description of the solution cited in the link. Could you add that information to your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it helps I use Helicon remote on my S3
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=helicon+remote
You will need an adaptor cable which is 99p of ebay.
This little app lets you take up to 15 bracketed shots with up to a 2 stop gap (too much for the D5100). You can also do this in manual mode so vary the stops per shot.

It also does time lapse (built in to the D5100 any way)
Record video
displays hyperfocal range
burst photos (preset ie takes 5 photos)
focus bracketing (takes multiple photos from focus point A to B to increase dof - ideal for macro)

the app is free in jpg mode. to take raw is paid for app.

Answer (score 0):

On my Canon if you set the self-timer, either 2 or 10 secs (I use 2), then the camera fires all 3 bracketed shots by itself automatically, one after the other.